# Smartest way to save an integer and a date with yml

Tags: java, yaml

I want to make sort of a transaction history in java. Everytime a transaction occurs, the amount of money being transfered and what time it was transfered. I then want to access the six latest transactions and see how long its been since the transaction (i.e. "You got paid 1000 USD 2 days ago).

I'm currently saving the data with yml with the following code and this format:

`add/remove (depending if the money was paid or recived) : amount : time`

Is there a better way to store this data so I can achieve the two tasks mentioned above? (Access six latest + how long since transaction).

```
    public void transactionHistoryOnAdd(UUID playerName, double addedCoinAmount) {
        List<String> list = this.config.getStringList("economy.bank.history." + playerName.toString());
        list.add("add:" + addedCoinAmount + ":" + System.currentTimeMillis());
        this.config.set("economy.bank.history." + playerName.toString(), list);
        save();
    }
```

Comment: *better* tends to be subjective. If you don't like your current approach, you should describe what exactly you dislike about it so that we have some idea about what *better* means for you.

Comment: @flyx The problem I'm having with my current approach is that I need to first get the data, split the data, sort the dates and then I have the values I want. My question is if there is a method where I can skip some of these steps and/or do it more efficiently.

Comment: Well it certainly would make sense to use YAML to encode the values. However you don't show enough code for us to propose changes. What is `this.config`, what does `save()` do?

Comment: `public CoinConfig(Core core) {

  this.file = new File(core.getDataFolder(), "coins.yml");

  if (!this.file.exists()) {

   try {
    this.file.createNewFile();
   } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
  }

  this.config = YamlConfiguration.loadConfiguration(this.file);
 }`

 `public void save() {
  try {
   this.config.save(this.file);
  } catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }`

@flyx

Comment: @flyx save() just saves the file and this.config is a yml file. See the code above

Comment: Please read about creating a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). *Just saves the file* does not tell us which YAML implementation you're using. Also, please edit your question instead of posting code in comments. `YamlConfiguration` does not belong to the most widely used YAML APIs SnakeYAML and Jackson, so information about the YAML implementation you use would be helpful (preferably with a tag, if one exists for it).